# Initialize array holding struct more efficiently

Tags: arrays, for-loop, struct, rust

I have the following code:

```
const N: usize = 10000;
const S: usize = 7000;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct T {
    a: f64,
    b: f64,
    f: f64
}

fn main() {
    let mut t: [T; N] = [T {a: 0.0, b: 0.0, f: 0.0}; N];

    for i in 0..N {
        t[i].a = 0.0;
        t[i].b = 1.0;
        t[i].f = i as f64 * 0.25;
    }

    for _ in 0..S {
        for i in 0..N {
            t[i].a += t[i].b * t[i].f;
            t[i].b -= t[i].a * t[i].f;
        }
        println!("{}", t[1].a);
    }
}
```

I'm unsure why the array `t` must be initialized that way. The first for-loop is intended to initialize the array with the containing struct to their respective values.

When I try to omit the initialization directly with the array:

```
let mut t: [T; N];
```

I get the following error:

> error[E0381]: use of possibly uninitialized variable: t

All for-loops are intended to be as such, I just want to know if there is a smarter way for the array and it's initialization with the first for-loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm unsure why the array `t` must be initialized that way.

Because Rust doesn't let you touch (entirely or partially) uninitialised values.  The compiler isn't smart enough to prove that the loop will *definitely* initialise everything, so it just forbids it.

Now, the *optimiser* is a different story.  That *can* notice that the initialisation is redundant and skip it... in theory.  It doesn't appear to do so with that code and the current compiler.  Such is optimisation.

> I just want to know if there is a smarter way for the array and it's initialization with the first for-loop.

The smart way is to just leave the code as-it-is.  Statistically speaking, it's unlikely to be a bottleneck.  If profiling suggests that it *is* a bottleneck, then you can use [`uninitialised`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html).  However, note that doing so can lead to undefined behaviour if you use it wrong.  Although not an exhaustive list, you *definitely avoid* using it on any type that is not `Copy`.

If you do *need* to use it, I strongly recommend also adjusting the first loop to make forgetting to initialise an element *or* a field in the structure impossible:

```
    let mut t: [T; N] = unsafe { ::std::mem::uninitialized() };

    for (i, e) in t.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        *e = T {
            a: 0.0,
            b: 1.0,
            f: i as f64 * 0.25,
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you use `std::ptr::write(e, t)` rather than `*e = t` does it eliminate the `Copy`-only restriction?

Comment: @ildjarn: That's got nothing to do with it.  I said that because non-`Copy` types can have custom `Drop` logic, which can cause Bad Things™ to happen if you make a mistake and drop uninitialised memory.  The sort of people who don't need to follow that advice are the sort of people who've already read the [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/), and aren't likely to need advice from the likes of me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::mem::uninitialized()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html). Note, however, that it is considered unsafe and needs to be marked as such:

```
let mut t: [T; N] = unsafe { std::mem::uninitialized() };
```

As stated by the aforelinked docs:

> This is useful for FFI functions and **initializing arrays** sometimes,
>   but should generally be avoided.